# XCode 4.5 Command Line Build Error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I am using Xcode 4.5 and using terminal command line "xcodebuild" to build my application. But I am getting following error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC "build/Sample_google.build/Release-iphoneos/Tech Time.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate.o" Sample_google/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC "build/Sample_google.build/Release-iphoneos/Tech Time.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MainViewController.o" Sample_google/Classes/MainViewController.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC "build/Sample_google.build/Release-iphoneos/Tech Time.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ChildBrowserCommand.o" Sample_google/Plugins/ChildBrowserCommand.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC "build/Sample_google.build/Release-iphoneos/Tech Time.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MainViewController.o" Sample_google/Classes/MainViewController.m normal armv7s objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC "build/Sample_google.build/Release-iphoneos/Tech Time.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/AppDelegate.o" Sample_google/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal armv7s objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(5 failures)
```

Please suggest a solution for this error. It is occurring since long.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Does the project build OK from within Xcode ?

Comment: yes.... it compiles fine from Xcode..

Comment: You should probably post the exact command line that you are using to invoke xcodebuild (i.e. add it to your question).

Comment: your question is tagged OS X but the build output looks iOS, which are you actually using?

Comment: I am using xcodebuild directly in the command line of terminal after navigating to the folder that contains the .xcodeproj file

Comment: @Wain I am using iOS. Corrected the tag. It was an auto selection by mistake.

Comment: The `osx` tag is probably appropriate as you're running the tools on OS X. Anyway, please post the actual command line being used.

Comment: @Wain On terminal, I first navigated to the folder that contained my .xcodeproj. After that I typed "xcodebuild" and hit enter. The above error comes.

Comment: Do you have a space in the folder path to your project? If so, remove it. If not, do you have multiple copies of Xcode installed? Do you have a setting for 'XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE' in your terminal profile?

Comment: I have multiple xcodes installed in my system. One is 4.3 and other is 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue. I solve it by adding the scheme configuration to xcodebuild command. Please refer to the sample code below.

```
xcodebuild -scheme "QuickView" -project "$PATH_PROJECT" -configuration Release
```

Thanks

Chamath Jeevan
Technical Lead
Gmail    : chamathjeevan@gmail.com
Skype   : chamathjeevan
Linkin    : http://lk.linkedin.com/in/chamathjeevan
Mobile   :+94 777 998 445